# How to delete temporarily created files in AWS using boto 3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am downloading a file from AWS using boto 3 and after processing I am trying to delete that file from server. Deleting a file seems to be confusing (as I am kinda new to AWS and boto), here is what I am doing:

```
    def test(self, obj):
        current_bucket = obj.bucket
        current_key = obj.key
        client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_ID, aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_KEY)
        client.download_file(current_bucket, current_key, "temp.file")
        # do the file processing
        # delete the temp.file
```

Is there any specific keyword in boto 3 to delete the temporarily created files??

Comment: Why not just do os.remove("temp.file") ?

Comment: yeah I was thinking about to do that but was not sure if its a good idea to import os there

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just process a file and then delete it.Then you should try reading it directly from s3 using [get_object()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object)

code in python will look something like:

```
# get Streaming Body
response = s3.get_object(Bucket='my_bucket', Key='s3_object')
lines = TextIOWrapper(response)

for line in lines:
    print(line)
```